# Override Related List's New button to open Screen Flow in a modal

Tags: visual-workflow, custom-button, button-overrides, admin, screen-flow

I want to create a button on the related list which could open up a Screen flow as a modal.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't do this directly.

However, you can create a component to house the flow and launch that component in a modal from the list view button. There's an example of this as an answer to this question:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005Z2NQAU